# AngularJs bootstrap $modal.open() working only first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-bootstrap

I am using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (version .10).
I need to open a simple modal window on event click of full-calendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

I do that using

```
 select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    console.log('Calendar select event fired');
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'template.html',
                        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                            $scope.cancel = function () {
                                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                            };
                        },

                    });
```

This works first time and the modal opens and closes ok. 
However on 2nd click onwards the modal doesn't opens. The $modal.open is getting triggered and console shows no error.

The same exercise if it is done using ng-click works all time . This also need after writing a open function in controller.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

However my objective is to call the modal open from another directive using $modal.open.

What am I missing ?

appreciate your help.

[Plunker Illustration here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ItEqZp?p=preview)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer this question without more details (ideally a minimal reproduce scenario using plunker).

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ItEqZp?p=preview

Comment: The plunker is broken

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your controller function apart like

```
controller : 'sampleCtrl'
```

and then do:

```
var sampleCtrl=function(){}
```

Implement your functionality in this function, this will solve your problem.